# I am getting "LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg"

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ i|i|i }

Dimnsions in nanoscale & Property &example\\\hline
3D Nanodots & All dimensions lie in nanoscale & fullerenes \\
2D Nanosheets & 2 dimensions lie in nanoscale & asbestos fibres\\
1D Nanofibers & 1 dimension lies in nanoscale & Carbon nanotubes\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
\end{table}
```

Comment: What should the i in the tabular preamble do?

Comment: May be a typo: sometimes "l" and "i" look quite the same ...

Comment: Thank for the response it was a typing error

Answer (score 1):

I think You just overlooked that `i` actually is `l`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l|l|l }

Dimnsions in nanoscale & Property &example\\\hline
3D Nanodots & All dimensions lie in nanoscale & fullerenes \\
2D Nanosheets & 2 dimensions lie in nanoscale & asbestos fibres\\
1D Nanofibers & 1 dimension lies in nanoscale & Carbon nanotubes\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works ! thanks a lot. ur right it was a typo

Comment: @VishalPatil You are welcome!